# Option proofing: Analytical solution for option math

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-management, mathematics

How do I prove the following equation:

P(X=100)≤(P(X=110)-P(X=90))/2

I am not sure how to start and whether it involves using the Black-Sholes formula or not (something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LM6iMfHbQDs&t=939s). Also, please note that this is an option price of a put, not a probability.

Thank you!

Comment: I think what you want is actually $P(X=100)≤\frac{P(X=110) + P(X=90))}{2}$.That is, the convexity of the option price.

Comment: I think yes, there is a mistake in the sign.

Answer (score 1):

The pair of puts *has* to be more valuable. Consider the payoff at expiry - it looks like this:

[image: Put Portfolio Payoff]

The pair of puts pay off the same or more in every scenario (usually the same, but more when you're between 90 or 110) so they *MUST* be more valuable.

This is actually related to the convexity of the option payoff profile... it's duscussed further in [this question and answers](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55995/strike-arbitrage/55999#55999)

Comment: Hi, much more clearer. So this is basically a butterfly spread and I just need to calculate the payoff, right? I thought that this involves doing some integrals ...

Comment: It's definitely true that you can compare BS fomulae for different options and strikes. But if all you want to show is that the K=90 and the K=110 puts must sum to give more than twice the price of the K=100 put, then the above is sufficient. At expiry, there is a positive probability of the portfolio being worth more and NO chance it is worth less. Since today's price is the discounted future price in the RN measure (ie. $C(0) = \delta(0,t){\mathbb E}[C(t)]$), this means the portfolio *MUST*, *ALWAYS* be more expensive.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to help me this too? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57434/binary-option-risk-neutral-valuation